Bind9 DNS over HTTPS (DoH)
I'm interested to make my bind9 server DOH ready and read any config examples. Then i read:  bind9 DOH is designed to work just between the client and the local bind9 server - not between the local bind9 and configured forwarder.
Is that correct?

Yes, that is correct. Version 9.19 is needed for forwarding via DNS over TLS. But forwarding over DoH is not implemented in any version (nor is needed). DoH is just server side in bind9. dnsdist might be used to forward over DoH or DoQ, but bind9 itself cannot do that.
Client DoH is implemented just in dig tool, not in named itself.
